# word order for a relative clause - "Mr. X is her doctor she visits twice a month." / "Mr. X she visits twice a month is her doctor."

Tags: relative-clauses

> Mr. X **is her doctor she visits twice a month**.
>
> Mr. X **she visits twice a month is her doctor**.

Do both sentences sound good? Is there the rule which word order to choose better?

**Addition:**
If the second sentence is wrong, could you explain why?
In my grammar book I have an example: **"The people we met were very friendly"**. I don't see the difference in the structure between the mentioned example in my grammar book and the second sentence.

Comment: We normally address doctors by their title, "Dr. Pitt, whom I see twice a month, is a wonderful physician"  "Dr Destri, my cousin, is also my doctor."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must be intending *she visits twice a month* to be a relative clause with omitted *that/who/whom*.

But we can only omit this for a restrictive (defining) relative clause. For a non-restrictive (commenting) relative clause, there is a new breath group (usually written with a comma), and the relativiser is required.

But *Mr X, her doctor* presumably defines Mr X adequately, so the relative clause must be nonrestrictive, and *that/who/whom* cannot be omitted.

Once you restore the relativiser,

> Mr. X is her doctor, who she visits twice a month.

and

> Mr. X, who she visits twice a month, is her doctor.

are both equally grammatical.

Comment: I have tried to understand your information with my grammar book. If I understand you right, these sentences can omit "that": "He doesn’t like the food you cook." & "The food you cook isn’t tasty." Right?

Comment: That's right, @Sergei.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct, but the second one is just wrong, the word order is jumbled and does not make sense. However you might try one of these:

> Mr X is her doctor, she visits **him** twice a month.
> Mr X is her doctor **whom** she visits twice a month.
> She visits Mr X, her doctor, twice a month,

They all mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your first proposed sentence is a comma splice.  There should be some kind of conjunction between the two clauses.

Comment: If you insist "Mr X is her doctor **and** she visits him twice a month".